# Spectrum of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Are there in literature, any works about the set of prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$?

Thank you.

Comment: This should be a fun exercise for either an algebraic geometry or number theory course at the graduate level. What specific question are you looking to answer about these prime ideals and what efforts of your own have you made so far?

Comment: Follow [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561960/prime-and-primary-ideals-in-mathbbz-sqrt5?rq=1), and replace $5$ by $10$.

Comment: At which $p$ is it ramified ? Is it a Dedekind domain ? How do you find the prime ideals above $p$ ? Next the main knowledge is quadratic reciprocity, telling when $(p)$ is a prime ideal. Discussing the ideal classes is fun too.

Comment: This is a Dedekind domain that is not PID.

Comment: We know also that $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$ is an integral extension, and that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}] \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{x^2-10}$.

Comment: The set $A=\{a+b\sqrt{10} \;\; | \;\; a,b \in p\mathbb{Z}\}$, where $p$ is a prime integer, is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$, such that $A \cap \mathbb{Z}=p\mathbb{Z}$. It is right?